# I’m a EU citizen with a job offer in Switzerland. Will my non EU spouse be allowed to work there automatically?

Tags: eu-citizens, switzerland, work-permit

My company is transferring me to Switzerland and I am a Spanish citizen. Will my spouse, who is not an EU citizen, automatically have work rights in Switzerland? Would it be easy for him to get a job in Switzerland?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Switzerland has a bilateral agreement with the EU that implements a system almost (but not quite) the same as the one provided in the EU free movement directive (2004/38/EC).  The main difference that I am aware of is that you will need to get a residence permit.

In any event, your spouse will be authorized to work.  See [Free Movement of Persons Switzerland – EU/EFTA](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/fza_schweiz-eu-efta.html) on the site of the State Secretariat of Migration for more information, including a link to a page of [frequently asked questions](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/fza_schweiz-eu-efta/eu-efta_buerger_schweiz/faq.html), which include:

> Are family members allowed to work in Switzerland?
>
> Spouses and children of EU/EFTA nationals who are admitted to Switzerland under family reunification are legally entitled to work regardless of their nationality.

As to whether it will be easy to find a job, I cannot say.  It will depend on where you are, what kind of job he is looking for, and his qualifications.